# How to setup a helper for an Html extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I apologize for the somewhat vagueness of this question in advance.  I have setup a number of custom Html helpers to use in partial views...

What i am trying to do is set it up so if want  to change how the field is displayed, then I can use an extension.

The following:

```
@Html.FieldFor("Somefield", "Label name:", @Model.Somevalue)
```

will render a standard text box on the screen with with the Id of "SomeField" and a Label of "Label Name:" and the third element is what would be shown in the field itself.

Let's say I want to show the Value in `@Model.Somevalue` on the screen without it being in a text field if the value is not editable at that time...

In that case I would like to be able to have something like this...

```
@Html.FieldFor("Somefield", "Label name:", @Model.Somevalue).NotEditbable()
```

and use that in the helper to determine the code that is passed back. Can someone point me to a tutorial or other resource I can use to accomplish this?

below is the Helper in question if that is useful...

```
public static MvcHtmlString FieldFor(this HtmlHelper helper, string FieldName, string Label, string ValueContents = null)
    {
        return new MvcHtmlString(String.Format("<label for=\"{0}\">{1}</label><input id=\"{0}\" type=\"text\" Value = \"{2}\">", FieldName, Label, ValueContents));
    }
```

Comment: Is there any reason not to just add a `bool` paramter in your `FieldFor()` method?

Comment: I would like to use it for any of the custom helpers that I want without having to pass in a variable like that. I would then have to modify every one of the custom helpers to accept a variable for every type of change i want to make.

Eventually I would like to setup one for not only Displaying data like shown above, but also disabling as well as other reasons.

I know that it's possible, but I cannot remember the term given to it to look up how to do it.

Comment: Simply give it a default value for the `bool` so you don't have to change any existing code unless you want them to be readonly: `public static MvcHtmlString FieldFor(this HtmlHelper helper, string FieldName, string Label, string ValueContents = null, bool readonly=false)`. Adding extension method for `MvcHtmlString` is not impossible, but since the `MvcHtmlString` itself is already wrapped as a whole string, it can be tricky to edit the html generated in 2nd hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this [page](http://www.dotnetperls.com/extension) as a guide to setup a new extension method and then to create the method I switched the MVCHtmlString to a regular string... Made the alterations, I wanted to make and then re-encoded it to a MVCHtmlString...